# How to Validate Text box on depend of another Text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am Performing Calculation of Student fee Details,There are Two Text boxes,one which is automatically fixed(disabled)as Rs.5000,If i enter value below Rs.5000 value on another Text box then it will calculate subtraction and show balance in result text box.If i enter value above Rs.5000 it should not take that value in second text box.I want to validate text box depending on first text box value.
Here is my body part

    
my script part

```
  $(".maxmin").each(function () {

        var thisJ = $(this);
        var max = thisJ.attr("max") * 1;
        var min = thisJ.attr("min") * 1;
        var intOnly = String(thisJ.attr("intOnly")).toLowerCase() == "true";

        var test = function (str) {
            return str == "" || /* (!intOnly && str == ".") || */
                ($.isNumeric(str) && str * 1 <= max && str * 1 >= min &&
                (!intOnly || str.indexOf(".") == -1) && str.match(/^0\d/) == null);
                // commented out code would allow entries like ".7"
        };

        thisJ.keydown(function () {
            var str = thisJ.val();
            if (test(str)) thisJ.data("dwnval", str);
        });

        thisJ.keyup(function () {
            var str = thisJ.val();
            if (!test(str)) thisJ.val(thisJ.data("dwnval"));
        })
    });
```

Comment: By the way, what is the point of multiplying max and min by one? If your goal is to parse it as integers, theres the `parseInt()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do on textchanged something like this

```
$(textbox1).on('change', function () {
  if(textbox1.val()==5000){
     //do your code
  }
 else if(textbox1.val()<5000){
     //do your code
  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into the onchange (https://api.jquery.com/change/) or keyup events (https://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Get the values and perform your calculations.

Comment: This should be a comment when you can comment. This is not an answer